# TypeError: _firestore.default.initializeApp is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

In my app it is showing _firestore.default.initializeApp is not a function
Evaluating src/screens/Login.js, src/appNavigator.js, App.js

I have already added firebaseconfig and connected with the firebase.

I have added all dependencies in package.json properly.

Can anyone help me?

This is my Login.js code

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

import React, { useEffect } from "react";

import firebase from "@react-native-firebase/firestore"

const firebaseConfig = {
    ...
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const Login = ({navigation}) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        firebase.firestore()
            .collection("admin")
            .add()({
                email: "admin@gmail.com",
                password: "admin@1234"
            })
            .then(() => {
                console.log("Admin added!")
            })
    }, [])
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Admin Login</Text>
            <TextInput style={styles.inputStyle} placeholder={"Enter Email Id"} />
            <TextInput style={styles.inputStyle} placeholder={"Enter Password"} />
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginBtn}>
                <Text style={styles.btnText}>Login</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>
    )
}

export default Login;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: "800",
        color: "#000",
        marginTop: 100,
        alignSelf: "center"
    },
    inputStyle: {
        paddingLeft: 20,
        height: 50,
        alignSelf: "center",
        marginTop: 30,
        borderWidth: 0.5,
        borderRadius: 10,
        width: "90%"
    },
    loginBtn: {
        backgroundColor: "orange",
        width: "90%",
        height: 50,
        alignSelf: "center",
        height: 50,
        borderRadius: 10,
        marginTop: 50,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center"
    },
    btnText: {
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: '600',
        color: "black"
    }
})
```

This is my app.js code

```
 import {View, Text} from "react-native";

import React from "react";

 import AppNavigator from "./src/appNavigator";

  const App = () => {
    return <AppNavigator />
}

export default App;
```

Comment: To fix this error, make sure you have imported the firebase package correctly at the top of your file:

Then, instead of calling firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig) directly, you can try using the default export from the @react-native-firebase/app module to initialize Firebase:

`import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app;

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}`

Answer (score 0):

you need to do `import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";` and then instead of `firebase.initializeApp()` do `initializeApp(firebaseConfig)`.

Also don't give to everyone your firebaseConfig because anyone can destroy your database.

Comment: isn't this just v8 vs v9 implementation...?

Comment: @goAT2160 after adding import {initializeApp} from "@react-native-firebase/app" and updating initializeApp(firebaseConfig) it is showing (0 , _app.initializeApp) is not a function